# What is the displacement of the block, given force and mass?

Tags: kinematics

Suppose I have a block which has mass 2 kg. I apply a force of 10N. The object gets accelerated and then retards finally comes to rest. Given this much information, can we find the displacement of the block?

Please Help.
Thanks

Comment: The duration of action of force is necessary to calculate the final velocity. Also, any retarding force like friction must be given.

Comment: It depends on how much time does the force act on the block and the properties of the surface that the block is moving onto.

Comment: I'm assuming it was a one time force (not constantly applied), but either way you'd need the coefficient of friction to determine where it stops. If it starts moving as a result of the force then there is nothing stopping or slowing it down unless we know there is some resistive force.

Comment: Is it not possible to calculate displacement? If final velocity or time was their, we could have done it. OK let's suppose that there is a frictional force acting on the object. If we Take coefficient of kinetic friction as 0.25, I still don't get the way?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I am sorry to oppose you but this is not a homework question. Please don't report this. I thought it just like that I found that this platform will help me to discuss it

Comment: @ghaprameya It says homework _or_ **worked example** type questions.  This seems to be a worked example.

Comment: No I told you it is a thought experiment. I am trying hard to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose that the time in which the force acts on the block is $\Delta t=t_{2}-t_{1}$.
Using the second law of motion:
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x=\frac{1}{m}F$$
So the velocity is:
$$v=\frac{d}{dt}x=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\frac{1}{m}Fdt=\frac{1}{m}F\Delta t$$
Using this initial velocity, you can calculate the distance that the block travels until it stops with this formula:
$$\Delta KE=W$$
So:
$$-\frac{mv^2}{2}=-\mu mgd\cos\left(\theta\right)$$
If the surface is horizontal, $\theta=0$, so:
$$d=\frac{v^2}{2\mu g}$$
where $v$ is the initial velocity, $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction and $g$ is gravitational acceleration.

Comment: when initial velocity is 0, d=0?? How?

Comment: $v=0$ means that the block is not moving, so if it's not moving there will be no displacement of the block.

Comment: v is the initial velocity, $v$=o means that it is at rest. Then, will the force applied not make the displacement. If the coefficient of static friction is less than 0.5, then the block must move.Hmmm....